# How to turn off colored lighting?

Tags: rendering, lighting

Why is it colored? I just want normal lighting.[image]

Comment: Click on the rectangle under the Lamp Types and above the "Energy" value (That is currently purple) and change the color in the resulting pop up menu.

Comment: You can also Right Click the same rectangle and choose "Reset to Default".

Comment: @Dontwalk Could you clarify where "Lamp Types" is? Sorry I can't really see it. 

Comment: It's in your screen shot on the right... I will craft an answer and include an image.

Comment: Oh! That was obvious. But what color do I change it to then? I just want the original color of the character.

Comment: Change it to White or reset it to default as I described as the second option in the answer (Which is white).

Comment: I updated my answer with more clarification. If you feel it solved your issue you can mark it a solved. Happy Blendering!

Comment: @ Lana - "Why is my render a whiteish color though". This is a separate question. Please create a new question for this. There is no limit to the number of individual questions you can ask... It makes the site easier for people looking for answers to find them :) *Hint: It is probably too bright.

Comment: Oh! Sorry I didn't know, But it in at the default brightness, I don't understand why it's that color :( I just want the normal character, without all these effects.

Comment: Don't be sorry... it's ok. Read my answer about color. Just create a new question about the brightness (You will be helping others by doing this) with screen grabs and what you have done etc. you will get the answers you need.

Answer (score 2):

You need a lamp(s) in your scene (Which you have) in order to see the rendered image. You must have inadvertently changed the default color of your lamp (which is white) to purple. The default color *white* is actually neutral, no color. If you change the lamps color to anything but white the lamp will actually cast *that color* into your scene.

To fix this either

Click on the rectangle under the Lamp Types and above the "Energy" value (That is currently purple for you) and change the color in the resulting pop up menu to white.

or

You can also Right Click the same rectangle and choose "Reset to Default". This would be the least desirable as you would have to reposition the new lamp.

Or you could delete the current lamp and add a new one. This would be the least desirable option as you would have to position the new lamp which is more work.

[image]